# Android Studio won't import packages and @override method automatically for flutter app development

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, flutter

Auto completion or auto import packages/override methods in **Android Studio for Flutter** doesn't work. Every time i need to write the code manually.

But while coding with native android or java, it imports packages and override methods automatically. In-fact i configure for auto import/code generation under

> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Dart -> Code Generation

[image]

Is there any other process to configure android studio for auto completion ?

***Or should i use IntelliJ IDEA ?***

Comment: It does work. You might have setup the Flutter and Dart plugins wrong, but I cannot tell.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I re-install plugins and it doen't work. And in vs code editor, it works perfectly. But i prefer android studio.

Comment: What SDK path do you have selected in the Flutter plugin? What's the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks man, after running "flutter doctor -v" command, it suggest me to upgrade. And after upgrading, problem solves. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear :D

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an [open issue in GitHub](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44321) related to it. And both happening in Android Studio and VS Code. Currently, the workaround could be [upgrading](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading) to the [latest Flutter version](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases). Sometimes if you are using channels like `dev` could also [result in this kind of issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels#which-channel-should-i-use), switching to `master` or `stable` could be a remedy to this.