# Flutter/Dart autocomplete works in VS Code, but not in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, visual-studio-code

I thought AS was the one primary supported environment when it comes to develop, so this is really unusual.

`Alt + Enter` in `Android Studio`

- Flutter Plugin: v35.2.1
- Dart Plugin:  v183.6270

[image: Android Studio]

**The very same project opened in VS Code**, after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238710/android-studio-wont-import-packages-and-override-method-automatically-for-flut).

`Ctrl + .` in `VS Code`

- Flutter Plugin: v.2.26.1
- Dart Plugin: v2.26.1

[image]

Flutter:

`flutter --version`

```
Flutter 1.2.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8661d8aecd (3 months ago) • 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
Engine • revision 3757390fa4
Tools • Dart 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)
```

---

WHY IS THAT?

Answer (score 3):

Auto-complete is now available in Android studio also. If it is doesn't work for you, go to File->Power Save Mode and disable it.

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3456#issuecomment-593689793_

Comment: Finally I found out why this was suddenly not working anymore. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered on [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3456#issuecomment-489654313).

> Android Studio has an older
>   version of the Dart plugin (183.6270) than IntelliJ (191.7019). That
>   newer Dart plugin supports the feature of the analysis server that
>   shows completions for symbols that are not in scope. If you select one
>   of these symbols, your imports will be updated for you automatically.
>
> As Android Studio revs, and moves to a version of the IntelliJ
>   platforms that supports the new Dart plugin, Android Studio will get
>   this feature as well.

Tldr:
`IntelliJ` and `VS Code` have more up-to-date versions than `Android Studio`.

Comment: Is this available in Android studio now?

Answer (score 2):

From the navbar click on file -> settings -> intentions then search for dart
check the option {Quick assist }

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.
Go to Preferences >> Editor >> General >> Code Completion

Change (show the parameter info popup in 200 ms instead of 1000 ms )
also (show the documentation popup in 200. ms instead of 1000 ms )

This helps to make work faster and you can check other settings on this page

[image]