# Quick Docs won't display automatically in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

As other posts have mentioned, I've already checked the following:

```
File->Settings->Editor->General->"Show quick documentation on mouse move  Delay(ms):  500"
```

And I've also already downloaded the SDK

```
Android SDK->SDK Tools tab->"Documentation for Android SDK"
```

And I've also tried restarting Android Studio but that didn't help either.

This is what I see when I hover over the selection that I want the quick docs to show up for:

[image: what_i_see]

The only way I can get the quick docs to show up, if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>.

I'm using Android Studio 3.5.3.

How can I get the quick docs to show up automatically without having to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> every single time?

Here's a screenshot of what Quick Docs looks like

[What Quick Docs looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVkrn.png)

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow! For future readers it is best to embed images directly in the question as those posted on external services might disappear making your question not understandable.

Comment: I tried, but it said that I was too new of a user and that in order to do that I needed points of 10 or higher.

Comment: I did the edit for you then, you are right I forgot about this limitation. Edit is in peer review, it should show up soon.

Comment: Thank you.  Hopefully that will make a difference, as no one has responded yet.  I'm hesitant to open a bug on Android Studio if someone has seen this before, but I may have to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter/Dart autocomplete works in VS Code, but not in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990257/flutter-dart-autocomplete-works-in-vs-code-but-not-in-android-studio)

Comment: Also see https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3456

Comment: Autocomplete shows up fine.  The issue is Quick Docs does not unless I press Ctrl + q everytime.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you, do this:

1- Go to File-> Settings-> Editor-> General-> Code Completion

2- Check the "Show documentation popup in X ms"

That should do it. I used 500ms, seems to work fine.

Comment: This answer solves the problem in Android Studio 4 and in fairness should be accepted